# How to change window-numbering default key binding

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

The default key binding is below:

```
(defvar window-numbering-keymap
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map "\M-0" 'select-window-0)
    (define-key map "\M-1" 'select-window-1)
    (define-key map "\M-2" 'select-window-2)
    (define-key map "\M-3" 'select-window-3)
    (define-key map "\M-4" 'select-window-4)
    (define-key map "\M-5" 'select-window-5)
    (define-key map "\M-6" 'select-window-6)
    (define-key map "\M-7" 'select-window-7)
    (define-key map "\M-8" 'select-window-8)
    (define-key map "\M-9" 'select-window-9)
    map)
  "Keymap used in by `window-numbering-mode'.")
```

I want to use the key "Command (s)" instead of Meta, I change the key binding like this:

```
(define-key map "\s-1" 'select-window-1)
```

but it doesn't work. In minibuffer: s-1 is undefined.

Comment: Try `(kbd "s 1")` or `[(super 1)]` instead of `"\s-1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Drew said, changing `"\s-1"` to `(kbd "s-1")` works OK. Thank you Drew.